# How do you convert a JLabel to a Button in Java?

Tags: java, interface, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JLabel with ImageIcons of t-shirts. I want to make each t-shirt have the ability to be clicked and then it will lead to another window. How can I make each t-shirt a button while maintaining the pictures?
This is just part of one of my methods and I want the shirts to become JButtons.
Here is my code:

```
final JFrame shirts = new JFrame("T-shirts");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

        for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
           l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("T-shirts/"+i+".jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setFont(l.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            panel.add(l);
        }//end of for loop


        shirts.setContentPane(panel);
        shirts.setSize(1000, 1000);
        shirts.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        shirts.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: A JButton can display an icon too: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html#JButton%28javax.swing.Icon%29

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no need to change to a JButton. The simplest option here is to implement a MouseListener.

This will allow you to test for mouse clicked events:

---

```
yourLabelName.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
{  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
       //point to the frame you want it to go to from here
       yourFrame = new JFrame("Next JFrame");
       frame.setVisible(true);

    }  
});
```

---

> UPDATE

```
shirts.this.add(l);
```

That will add the label to the next JFrame

---

Hope this helps.

Let me know of the outcome :)

Comment: Thank you. The MouseListener really helped. Do you know, based on my code, how to detect which JLabel was clicked?

Comment: For that you will need to create an array list of JLabels. From that point forward, you do exactly what you are doing, but just add the Label to the ArrayList, so that you can check if it was label 1, 2, 3, 4 so on, by getting the label based on the name of it (given by i)

Comment: I made the array list and then added the label to the array list. How do I check which label was clicked? Here is code where l is the JLabel: panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
{  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
    {  
       //point to the frame you want it to go to from here
      select.add(l);
       JFrame sizes = new JFrame("Shopping");
       sizes.setVisible(true);
       sizes.setSize(500, 500);
       sizes.setLocation(100,200);
       //select.add(l);
       shirts.dispose();
    }  
});

Comment: Can you quickly tell me the reason as to why you require to know which label was clicked, that way I know how to answer. Thanks

Comment: I want to display the image that was selected in the label in the next frame.

Comment: So basically you want to do what you were doing initially, for instance, assigning the incrementing number into the name of the image location? "T-shirts/"+i+".jpg"

Comment: Yes but how can I determine which image was clicked?

Comment: you can just say "e.getSource();" .. that will show you which label was clicked

Comment: Where would i put that and then how could i add the selected image to the new frame?

Comment: I don't really see the need for you to know which was clicked. For what you are performing, it is a lot of work to accomplish. In order to get the image into the new frame, its quite simple. Refer to my answer again, I have pasted the code you need to add the image

Comment: Not a problem. Please give my answer correct, if I helped you at all :)